# How to install on a mac and get rid of OSX

Tags: macosx

I would like to install ubuntu on a mac instead of running OSX.
How Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need [rEFIt](http://rodsbooks.com/refind/) to be able to do the dual boot.

Comment: Your webpage says its no longer maintained and has a link to this. (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is this the same thing?

Comment: yes it's the same

Answer (score 0):

You do not need refit or refind to boot ubuntu from a mac if you are doing a single boot.  In fact grub2 can handle booting of osx and ubuntu so it's not necessary at all.

Advice getting native ubuntu on mbp from experience:

1. Back up your data.
2. Create an OSX recovery disk/usb found [here](http://www.apple.com/osx/recovery/).
3. Boot recovery disk and use diskutility to reformat and repartition the drive. You will need a partition for the filesystem and another for a swap partition.
4. Reboot into live cd - select something else - make sure your installation will not touch the EFI partition. Change the option to "Do not use".
5. Install ubuntu but do not reboot (continue testing). You may get an error during installation about being unable to install a bootloader, ignore it for now and continue.
6. Run boot-repair (available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)) and follow instructions to install grubEFI.

Thats it, you can now reboot and enjoy ubuntu running natively on a mbp.

NOTE: If you are wishing to have a dual boot then follow the steps above without deleting or reformatting your osx partition.  Grub will detect the osx efi once you have run boot-repair.